# Let $G=\{A \in F$ such that two probability measures agree$\}$, show that $G$ is a $\lambda$-system.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let ($\Omega,F$) be sample and event spaces. My instructor said the proof has some holes so I’m hoping to get a second look.

First, $\Omega\in G$ is trivial. A probability measure needs to include an entire sample space.

Second, let $A,B\in G, A \subset B$. $P(B-A)=P(B)-P(A)$ which is in $[0,1]$. Thus, $B-A \in G$. My idea is if two sets are in $G$, their difference are in $G$ too.

Lastly, $A_i \uparrow A$ and $A_i \in G$. Using property of measures, $P(A_i) \uparrow P(A)$ too. $P(A) \in [0,1]$ so $A\in G$. However, I was told that I need to use property of measures twice here.

Comment: It should be a $\lambda$ system.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the typo.

Comment: As you are trying to work on the class on which two probability measures agree it is weird you only work with one. Except from this detail your proof is fine.

Comment: @blamethelag could I ask for an elaboration? The second part was advised by my instructor. But I thought it’s weird too that there’s no $P_1$ and $P_2$ defined.

Comment: From a rigorous point of view you proved nothing. You should fix $P_1,P_2$ and prove that $G$ is a $\lambda$-system. All the ideas are in your post.